# trace of product of positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

For positive definite matrices $A$ and $C$, positive semidefinite matrices $B$ and $D$, I want to know whether $tr\{ABCD\}=0$ implies that $tr\{BD\}=0$.

Comment: If I add a constraint on the setting. For positive definite matrices $A$ and $C$, positive semidefinite matrices $B$ and $D$. This time $A=(B+D+eI)^{-1}$, $C=(B+D+fI)^{-1}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, $e$ and $f$ are both positive numbers. It is obvious that under this setting $tr\{BD\}=0$ implies $tr\{ABCD\}=0$. However I want to know whether $tr\{ABCD\}=0$ implies that $tr\{BD\}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Let $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $D=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, and $A=C=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$.  Then $\mathrm{tr}(BD)=0$, but $\mathrm{tr}(ABCD)=1$.

Comment: Thanks! but whether $tr\{ABCD\}=0$ implies $tr\{BD\}=0$?

Comment: Jim, you showed him the wrong implication.

Comment: @VedranŠego He didn't. The OP edited the question *after* Jim answered.

Comment: Ah, I apologize then.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let

$$A := {\rm I}_2 := \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
B := \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
C := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
D := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then:
$$ABCD = 0, \quad BD = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$
so
$$\mathop{\rm tr}(ABCD) = 0, \quad \mathop{\rm tr}(BD) = 1.$$